# Add IP addresses on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, ipv4, address

I have a 12 IPv4 addresses that I need to add to a CentOS 6.3 machine however those 12 IPs are spread out among 3 different subnets. I know how to add additional IPs when they are on the same subnet, but how can I do it with different subnets?

Is there a certain value to put in the ifcfg-eth0-range1 file such as GATEWAY=X.X.X.X?

Thanks

Comment: The same way. Whether they're on the same or different subnets makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Create subinterfaces:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1
IPADDR=172.16.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONPARENT=yes

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:2
IPADDR=10.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONPARENT=yes
```

You could combine this with range files if you wish, and if your IPs are all consecutive.